# Search all date and dates between two date with specific time

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble how to do this, this is the original query

```
$this->db->query(
    '
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        lodgebookings 
    WHERE 
        lodge_name = "willow" 
    AND 
        (
            (
                checkin_date_user BETWEEN "' . date('Y-m-d',strtotime($book_date)) . ' 14:30:00" 
            AND 
                "' . date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 day',strtotime($book_date))) . ' 11:30:00"
            )
        OR
            (
                "' . date('Y-m-d',strtotime($book_date)) . ' 14:30:00" 
            BETWEEN 
                checkin_date_user 
            AND 
                checkout_date_user
            )
        )
    '
);
```

Now this query only returns the data depending on the $book_date
what i want to do is return the data without $book_date, it means all date
and all date between all checkin_date_user AND checkout_date_user that has 
a time 14:30:00

update: i already used time this is my code

```
$query = $this->db->query(
    '
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            lodgebookings 
        WHERE 
            lodge_name = "willow" 
        AND 
            TIME(checkin_date_user) = "14:30:00" 
        AND 
            (
                (
                    "' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($book_date)) . ' 14:30:00" 
                BETWEEN 
                    checkin_date_user 
                AND 
                    checkout_date_user
                ) 
            )
        '
    );
```

it still needs the $book_date and of course it will only return the data depends on $book_date..if i don't use $book_date it returns null

update:

actually it really won't return anything because i only have  11:30:00 for all the checkout_date_user..
if for example
checkin =2013-10-19 14:30:00
checkout=2013-10-20 11:30:00
i will not have any problem at all i can just query checkin
my problem is with between dates
checkin =2013-10-19 14:30:00
checkout=2013-10-21 11:30:00

i need to get the dates before the checkout date

Comment: Use the `time()` function to search time.

Comment: @Nil'z please see the update of my question.. i already used time()..thank you

Comment: select * from table where lodge_name = "willow" AND ( time(checkin_date_user) = '14:00:00' and time(checkout_date_user) = '14:00:00' )

Comment: @Nil'z it returned null also

 $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM lodgebookings WHERE lodge_name = "willow" AND ( time(checkin_date_user) = "14:00:00" AND time(checkout_date_user) = "14:00:00" )');

Comment: actually it really won't return anything because i only have  11:30:00 for all the checkout_date_user..
if for example
checkin =2013-10-19 14:30:00 
checkout=2013-10-20 11:30:00
i will not have any problem at all i can just query checkin
my problem is with between dates
checkin =2013-10-19 14:30:00 
checkout=2013-10-21 11:30:00

i need to get the dates before the checkout date

Comment: Do you want the dates between checkin and checkout? checking date is `$book_date` and checkout date is today and you want to count the number of days in between is that you want?

Comment: yes the dates between checkin and checkout, with 14:30:00 so the checkout date will not be included in the result..i must not specify a $book_date if i do that only result on $book_date will be shown..
so for 
book A (checkin =2013-10-19 14:30:00 , checkout = 2013-10-20 11:30:00) 
book B (checkin =2013-10-21 14:30:00 , checkout = 2013-10-22 11:30:00)
..that's just example because there's a lot of booking..i need to query all those booking that has a date and time 14:30:00 between checkin and checkout,

Comment: @Nil'z what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from my_table where checkout_date_user < date_add(checkout_date_user, - interval 1 day) AND checkin_date_user >= date_add(checkin_date_user, interval 1 day)
```

Comment: i think i pasted it wrong please correct me..


SELECT * FROM lodgebookings WHERE checkout_date_user < date_add(checkout_date_user, - interval 1 day) AND checkin_date_user >= date_add(checkin_date_user, interval 1 day)

this is the code:

$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM lodgebookings WHERE checkout_date_user < date_add(checkout_date_user, - interval 1 day) AND checkin_date_user >= date_add(checkin_date_user, interval 1 day)');

Comment: my error is


You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '- interval 1 day) AND checkin_date_user >= date_add(checkin_date_user, interval ' at line 1